# What is the mental factor of Adhimokkkha (determination) use for?

Tags: theravada, traditions, meditation-classification, mental-factors

I am interested in what many ways [Adhimokkha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhimoksha)(determination) is used in meditation or other purposes in different traditions.

Comment: Is adhimokkha the same as "Resolution" from the 10 paramis?

Comment: Yes, it's the same and important enough to be developed into a parami. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the Mahasi tradition (and perhaps others), resolutions are used when training the mind so that a certain type of insight (vipassana stage) arises during the practice -- most often the supramundane stage (cessation/fruition, magga-phala-nana), but also the lower stages (from A&P up to equanimity). The object of the resolution is stated in the mind (or aloud) before the practice, then let go. See Mahasi's great *Practical Insight Meditation* for details on that.